# Paypal API - checkout.js - parse response error

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I've implemented this API on my Angular app. The issue is when I'm entering wrong shipping address the API is throwing the error:

Uncaught Error: An error was encountered while handling error
 Error: Request to post www.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment failed with 400 error. Correlation id: 3b331f9eaafa4, 3b331f9eaafa4

{
    "name": "VALIDATION_ERROR",
    "details": [
        {
            "field": "city",
            "issue": "Value is invalid"
        },
        {
            "field": "state",
            "issue": "Value is invalid"
        },
        {
            "field": "zip",
            "issue": "Value is invalid"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Invalid request - see details",
    "information_link": "developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors",
    "debug_id": "3b331f9eaafa4"
}

How do I parse the error in order to show a alert with the error's text? It's not JSON, so I don't know how to have it parsed.

Comment: it actually is JSON, so why you claim it would not be JSON? displaying these errors might be the wrong approach. better do not submit, while the city and state were not supplied... or use "Login with PayPal", in order to know the default shipping address on file, already.

Comment: "the city and state where not supplied" - Yes, they are: 
USA
San Jose
Colorado
1 Main St
95131
The issue is Colorado as it should be California and this causes the error. It's quite possible that a customer fills in wrong state or zip. In this case it just stops working and I need to show what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to match the JSON and then parse it to JSON using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). Once done you can use the `message` and `details` fields which contain the information related to the error.

```
var jsonString = errmsg.match(/\{.*\}/gm);

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the full error: 

"Error: Error: Request to post sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment failed with 400 error. Correlation id: a7e0f78da1be, a7e0f78da1be

{
    "name": "VALIDATION_ERROR",
    "details": [
        {
            "field": "city",
            "issue": "Value is invalid"
        }
    ]
}
(www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:14010:39)
(www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:2569:31)"

As you can see it's NOT JSON, it's an object.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
let res = error.message.match(/{([\s\S]*?)^}/gm);
console.log( JSON.parse( res[0] ) )
```

This will give a JSON to work with.